# Disable background color for types in VScode while using Rust

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I am using rust in vscode after sometime. VScode seems to be inferring the types and they are giving a blue background for it. I want the type inference but not the blue background for it. How can I disable it? It used to be just text with with light grey color .
[image]

Comment: customize the syntax highlighting colors and do this by theme, lots of answers here at SO about that, find the name of the TextMate Scope to use

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A while ago some updates to VScode tweaked the default behavior of InlayHint several times, which caused annoyance to many people.

You can add it to `settings.json` to bring back the original transparent background for InlayHint:

```json
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorInlayHint.background": "#00000000",
    },
}
```

If you want to customize the foreground color:

```json
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorInlayHint.foreground": "#868686f0",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

File>Preferences>Settings, search for color customizations, click "Edit in settings.json"

Here are my preferred settings for a dark theme.

```json
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "editorInlayHint.background": "#00000000",
      "editorInlayHint.foreground": "#666666FF",
    },
}
```